# Angular App insight error: 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.ts

Tags: angular, appinsights

I am trying to include app insight in my angular 10 app using this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-add-application-insights-to-an-angular-spa/):

I am getting exception in node module : @microsoft/applicationinsights-web tsconfig.json file:

> File 'c:/MyApp/UI/node_modules/@microsoft/applicationinsights-web/src/Init.ts' is not under 'rootDir'
> 'c:/MyApp/UI/node_modules/@microsoft/applicationinsights-web/AISKU/src'.  'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.ts

Now the problem is AISKU folder doesn't exist:

> c:/MyApp/UI/node_modules/@microsoft/applicationinsights-web/AISKU

Answer (score 0):

1. set references in package1's `tsconfig.json`

   {
   "compilerOptions": {
   "declarationDir": "dist",
   "rootDir": "src"
   },
   "include": ["src"],
   "references": [
   {
   "path": "../package2"
   }
   ]
   }
2. set composite in package2's `tsconfig.json`

   "compilerOptions": {
   "declarationDir": "dist",
   "rootDir": "src",
   "composite": true
   }